# Trouble validating JSON

Tags: javascript, json, database, csv

I'm having trouble getting the following JSON chunk validated. Any ideas why this is seemingly different from a normal chunk?

`{"query": {"pages": {"52000": {"revisions": [{"*": "{{#fte:imslppage\n\n| *****AUDIO***** =\n\n| *****FILES***** =\n===Parts===\n====Complete====\n{{#fte:imslpfile\n|File Name 2=PMLP52000-o.pdf\n|File Description 2=Complete Parts (B&W)\n|Page Count 2=170\n|Editor=\n|Image Type=Normal Scan\n|Scanner 2={{BSB}}\n|Uploader 2=[[User:Carmar1791|Carmar1791]]\n|Date Submitted 2=2008/10/6\n|Publisher Information=London: [[John Walsh]] [obscured by John Young's label]     n.d. (ca.1725)\n|Copyright=Public Domain\n|Misc. Notes=Pirated edition of the unauthorized Amsterdam print by Le Cene.\n|File Name 1=PMLP52000-tessarini_concerti_a5_op1_bsb_colour.pdf\n|File Description 1=Complete Parts (Colour)\n|Scanner 1={{BSB}}\n|Uploader 1=[[User:Fynnjamin|Fynnjamin]]\n|Date Submitted 1=2014/8/19\n}}\n\n| *****WORK INFO*****\n\n|Work Title=Concerti a Cinque     Con 3 Violini     Violetta     Violoncello o Basso Continuo\n|Alternative Title=12 Violin Concerti\n|Opus/Catalogue Number=Op.1 (so called by the publisher     not in accordance with the usual worklist)\n|Number of Movements/Sections=12 concerti\n|Dedication=\n|Year/Date of Composition=1715 ca.\n|Year of First Publication=1724 (Amsterdam: Le Cene)\n|Genre=Concerto\n|Librettist=\n|Language=\n|Piece Style=Baroque\n|Instrumentation=Violin solo     strings     continuo\n|Related Works=[[3 Violin Concertos (Tessarini     Carlo)]]     earlier versions of 3 of these published concertos\n|Tags=concertos ; vn str bc\n\n| *****COMMENTS***** =\n\n\n\n| *****END OF TEMPLATE***** }}"}]     "pageid": 52000     "title": "12 Concerti a cinque     Op.1 (Tessarini     Carlo)"     "ns": 0}}     "normalized": [{"from": "12_Concerti_a_cinque    _Op.1_(Tessarini    _Carlo)"     "to": "12 Concerti a cinque     Op.1 (Tessarini     Carlo)"}]}}`

Any help would be appreciate. The ultimate goal is to get this into a readable/digestible file from several thousand of these chunks.

Comment: JSLint is your friend

Answer (score 1):

As tymeJV suggested, use jsonlint.com to validate your json.

You are missing commas everywhere.

```
{
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "52000": {
                "revisions": [{
                    "*": "{{#fte:imslppage\n\n| *****AUDIO***** =\n\n| *****FILES***** =\n===Parts===\n====Complete====\n{{#fte:imslpfile\n|File Name 2=PMLP52000-o.pdf\n|File Description 2=Complete Parts (B&W)\n|Page Count 2=170\n|Editor=\n|Image Type=Normal Scan\n|Scanner 2={{BSB}}\n|Uploader 2=[[User:Carmar1791|Carmar1791]]\n|Date Submitted 2=2008/10/6\n|Publisher Information=London: [[John Walsh]] [obscured by John Young's label]     n.d. (ca.1725)\n|Copyright=Public Domain\n|Misc. Notes=Pirated edition of the unauthorized Amsterdam print by Le Cene.\n|File Name 1=PMLP52000-tessarini_concerti_a5_op1_bsb_colour.pdf\n|File Description 1=Complete Parts (Colour)\n|Scanner 1={{BSB}}\n|Uploader 1=[[User:Fynnjamin|Fynnjamin]]\n|Date Submitted 1=2014/8/19\n}}\n\n| *****WORK INFO*****\n\n|Work Title=Concerti a Cinque     Con 3 Violini     Violetta     Violoncello o Basso Continuo\n|Alternative Title=12 Violin Concerti\n|Opus/Catalogue Number=Op.1 (so called by the publisher     not in accordance with the usual worklist)\n|Number of Movements/Sections=12 concerti\n|Dedication=\n|Year/Date of Composition=1715 ca.\n|Year of First Publication=1724 (Amsterdam: Le Cene)\n|Genre=Concerto\n|Librettist=\n|Language=\n|Piece Style=Baroque\n|Instrumentation=Violin solo     strings     continuo\n|Related Works=[[3 Violin Concertos (Tessarini     Carlo)]]     earlier versions of 3 of these published concertos\n|Tags=concertos ; vn str bc\n\n| *****COMMENTS***** =\n\n\n\n| *****END OF TEMPLATE***** }}"
                }],
                "pageid": 52000,
                "title": "12 Concerti a cinque     Op.1 (Tessarini     Carlo)",
                "ns": 0
            }
        },
        "normalized": [{
            "from": "12_Concerti_a_cinque    _Op.1_(Tessarini    _Carlo)",
            "to": "12 Concerti a cinque     Op.1 (Tessarini     Carlo)"
        }]
    }
}
```